# How to display and adjust elements when using br tag?

Tags: html, css

This is my `jsFiddle` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y3JnZ/3/)

HTML Block:

```
 <span class="areas">
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item <br/> 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 4</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 5</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 6</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 7</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
div.arealist { display: block; clear: both; margin-top: 40px; }
div.arealist>span { display: inline-block; padding: 25px; }
div.arealist>span label { display: inline-block; }
div.arealist>span.group { width: 75px; border: 1px solid #d0d0d0; }
div.arealist>span.areas { width: 300px; border: 1px solid #d0d0d0; }
```

This is how the elements are displayed when we enter a `<br/>` tag within an element :[image]

I know that the `<br/>` tag just does what it needs to do so by introducing a line break here.

But my problem is how to display something like this ?[image]

Meaning, Items are still displayed in original order; But notice `Item 1`. It just `stacks` itself and auto-adjusts whenever a `<br/>` is present.

I tried defining some divs and spans but not satisfied with clumsy code. What is the best way of doing this ?

I'm using `angularjs`, `html5` in my project. Are there any inbuilt way of doing this ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I've updated the blocks. Thank you for your comment, though.

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed: No worries. Please do look at making a Stack Snippet next time, though, like Terry did in his answer. It's the `[<>]` button on the toolbar. Makes it easier for people to both see the problem and help you solve it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Sure, learnt something new today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can move `label` after `checkbox` , assign `id` for checkbox and bind it to `label`.

```
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
<label for="chk" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">Item <br/> 1</label>
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marrypen/9fdffyg0/).

Comment: That doesn't look like the OPs desired result. Why don't you assign `vertical-align:middle; text-align:center` to the label as well

Comment: Here is [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/sncq1m6g/4/r) that makes it look like the OP wants.

Comment: @MrLister : Exactly what I need :) Can you post an answer so I can accept ?

Comment: @MrLister I tried your advice and seems works good. how could this happen when setting styles for label will also effect checkboxes also?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. Naah, that would make it look like I took the best parts from different answers. There is enough material here as it is.

Comment: @MrLister thanks very much. I think I have found a new world to learn! :)

Comment: @Pengyy The answer to your question about vertical alignment is that elements in a line are always aligned to each other. In [this simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4gk5t6t6/), the second span has a bigger font size, which causes the first span to move down to match the baseline. That's just how it works.

Comment: @MrLister so if any of the elements in same line have a vertical-align style will also affect others. This is what I got from here, is this right?

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative of using CSS3 flexbox, which actually gets quite close to what you want. Contrary to popular belief, [flexbox is actually rather widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox): unless you want to extend support to IE9 and below. You need to apply flexbox on two levels though:

1. On the `span.areas` parent, because you want to distribute the individual `<label>` elements
2. Within each `<label>` element, as you want to position the checkbox such that it is vertically centered

There are of course other hacks such as `display: table-cell`, but I am generally in favour of flexbox due to its flexibility (no pun intended).

Here is a proof-of-concept example based on your code:

```css
div.arealist {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

/* span.areas to have flexbox,
   so we can distribute the label groups
*/
div.arealist>span {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 25px;
}

/* Each label to have flexbox as well,
   so we can center the checkbox vertically
*/
div.arealist>span label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

div.arealist>span.areas {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<div class="arealist">
  <span class="areas">
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item <br/> 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 4</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 5</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 6</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" />Item 7</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I what to do. Thanks for notifying about `flexbox`. Definitely a good read. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align:center` to the label element.

`div.arealist>span label { display: inline-block; text-align:center; }`

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
div.arealist>span label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: center` as below

> div.arealist>span label { display: inline-block;text-align:center }

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y3JnZ/9/)